# postgres: inserting array of custom type

Tags: java, postgresql, literals

I have:

```sql
CREATE TYPE Person AS (given_name VARCHAR,
                       family_name VARCHAR);
CREATE TYPE Contributors AS (directors person[],
                             actors person[]) ;
CREATE TABLE Catalogue (id serial, contributors Contributors)
```

And I want to insert the following array literal into the catalogue table's `contributors` field:

```
({},{(Song,Kang-ho),(Omar,Sharif)})
```

through the [JDBC Driver's PGobject](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html) value but im having difficulty doing so.

I have come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676361/9199853) and I kinda understand the problem.

I tried the following:

```
({}, "{(Song,Kang-ho),(Omar,Sharif)}")
```

but i got:

> ERROR: malformed record literal: "(Song" Detail: Unexpected end of input.

so i tried:

```
'({},"{(Song,Kang-ho),(Omar,Sharif)}")'
```

and also:

```
'({},"{'(Song,Kang-ho)','(Omar,Sharif)'}")'
```

but I get this error:

> ERROR: malformed record literal: .... Detail: Missing left parenthesis.

what's the syntax to use for nested row-fields inside an array literal?

Comment: Why not simply normalize your data model and use a proper one-to-many relationship with multiple tables instead of arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to figure out what you are actually trying, as you are only showing part of a statement and it is not clear where the part you show fits into the whole.

This works:

```
insert into catalogue values  (1,('{}', '{"(Song,Kang-ho)","(Omar,Sharif)"}'));
```

So does this:

```
insert into catalogue values  (1,'({},"{""(Song,Kang-ho)"",""(Omar,Sharif)""}")');
```

Comment: the second option worked except that I am having difficulty reading it later, as I am getting `SQL object of class java.lang.String cannot be cast to mapped class org.postgresql.util.PGobject.` persumably because it reads the supposed Contributors entry as a string. how can I add the type information to my array types and row types so that I can read them later? I tried to mirror the syntax used in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88dfc/3 namely ::mytype and ::mytype[] but that is giving me errors. what would the above look like with the type information added?

Comment: ie: `"{""(Song,Kang-ho)"",""(Omar,Sharif)""}"` works, but if I add the type at the end: `"{""(Song,Kang-ho)"",""(Omar,Sharif)""}"::person[]` it doesn't work. neither does: `"{""(Song,Kang-ho)"",""(Omar,Sharif)""}::person[]"`

Comment: The types are already there on the data as stored as dictated by the column types.  I don't think that changing how you do the insertion is going to change the retrieval.  You have a problem specifically with the retrieval, so that is a different question.

Comment: you're right. I am receiving it as a `PGobject` to then read its value but i am getting `SQL object of class java.lang.String cannot be cast to mapped class org.postgresql.util.PGobject.` which I don't know what to do with.

Comment: Alas I can't help with that part.